# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshall an XML that I got as a BLAST output from NCBI. Unfortunately it seems to fail where it shouldn't. The stacktrace I get is:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/blast_output.xml; lineNumber: 578; columnNumber: 17; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:911)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1774)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(XMLEntityScanner.java:1502)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.seekCloseOfStartTag(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1386)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:246)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2778)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    ... 37 more
```

The XML line referenced in stacktrace:

```
<Hsp_identity>8</Hsp_identity>
```

And the code for unmarshalling:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BlastOutput.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
return (BlastOutput) u.unmarshal(outputFile);
```

Maybe someone could explain what is failing here.

Comment: is that the end of the xml doc?  From the rror it looks like it's complaining about a missing end tag for the root node, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It is not the very end. The file is 602 lines long...

Comment: Well, the document is unbalanced, in other words you're missing a closing tag somewhere or it's misplaced.  I've had some weirdness with line numbers in various xml packages so that may not be exact.  My advice is to pull the xml file into eclipse or some such and format it, and see if you can't figure out which end tag is missing/misplaced.  Another option is to debug line 911 of XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl and see what end tag it's expecting vs. what's found.

Comment: While debugging I found that
if (fMarkupDepth != fEntityStack[fEntityDepth])
fMarkupDepth is 8 and fEntityStack value is 0.
While checking manually it seems that the depths are ok in the xml. Tried formating with eclipse and it worked so it seems that markup is ok as well.

Comment: Grasping at straws here, is it maybe an encoding mismatch?  Are you sure the declared `encoding="..."` in the XML declaration matches the real encoding that the file is saved in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem with your XML or a bug in the parser that is being used by JAXB in your configuration.  You could try unmarshalling an instance of `XMLStreamReader` to force a different parser to be used.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Demo demo = new Demo();

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        File outputFile = new File("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(outputFile));
        BlastOutput blastOutput = demo.unmarshalBlastOutput(xsr);
    }

    private BlastOutput unmarshalBlastOutput(XMLStreamReader xsr) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BlastOutput.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        return (BlastOutput) u.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

}
```

Comment: This helped me come to an answer but it was much simpler. As it seems I was writing to a file and using the same handle for unmarshalling. The file wasn't done with the writing and that is why it couldn't find matching xml tags (as it was missing some at the time). As file writer was put into a while before the unmarshalling I wasn't expecting anything weird to happen :)